# Why does App Script add a decimal to numbers in an array?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

A simple function which returns an array:

```
function getArray(){
    return [
        123456780,
        123456781,
    ];
}
```

When checked in Google App Script using `indexOf()` fails

```
if(getArray().indexOf(123456780) > -1){
    console.log("Found in Array");
}
```

I output the array to the console and got this:
    [123456780.0,123456781.0]

`indexOf()` should works with decimals (see [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/c24xavby/)).

I worked around this by making the array values a string using `.map(String)` and the check value using `.toString()`

Why does Apps Script behave this way? Am I solving the right problem?

Comment: I think that when your script is run at the script editor of Google Apps Script, ``getArray().indexOf(123456780) > -1`` becomes ``true``. Although I'm not sure whether this is the reason, you use ``console.log("Found in Array")``. Did you check the stackdriver? In Google Apps Script, when ``console.log()`` is used, the result can be seen at the stackdriver. If you want to confirm the result at the log of script editor, how about modifying ``console.log("Found in Array")`` to ``Logger.log("Found in Array")``? If I misunderstand your situation, I'm sorry.

Comment: There is no such thing as integer in javascript only number.  All numbers are 64 bit floating point.

Comment: @Tanaike The issue is that `getArray().indexOf(123456780)` should be `true`, but in App Script it is `false` - it is as if `123456780 != 123456780.0`.

Comment: @OsulliP Thank you for replying. In your script, ``console.log("Found in Array");`` is not run. Is my understanding correct? In order to understand correctly your situation, can you provide the complete script that your situation can be replicated? If you can do, please add it to your question. I would like to confirm and study about it.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?  I've come across this this evening.  It's infuriating